# How to get all 3 labels' sentiment from finbert instead of the most likely label's?

Tags: bert, transformer, sentiment-analysis, huggingface

I'm using bert to do sentiment analysis. I previous used cardiffnlp's twitter-roberta-base-sentiment, https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment.

It gives the the usage on its page.

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import softmax
import csv
import urllib.request

# Preprocess text (username and link placeholders)
def preprocess(text):
    new_text = []
 
 
    for t in text.split(" "):
        t = '@user' if t.startswith('@') and len(t) > 1 else t
        t = 'http' if t.startswith('http') else t
        new_text.append(t)
    return " ".join(new_text)

# Tasks:
# emoji, emotion, hate, irony, offensive, sentiment
# stance/abortion, stance/atheism, stance/climate, stance/feminist, stance/hillary

task='sentiment'
MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-{task}"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)

# download label mapping
labels=[]
mapping_link = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cardiffnlp/tweeteval/main/datasets/{task}/mapping.txt"
with urllib.request.urlopen(mapping_link) as f:
    html = f.read().decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    csvreader = csv.reader(html, delimiter='\t')
labels = [row[1] for row in csvreader if len(row) > 1]

# PT
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
model.save_pretrained(MODEL)

text = "Good night "
text = preprocess(text)
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
output = model(**encoded_input)
scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
scores = softmax(scores)

# # TF
# model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
# model.save_pretrained(MODEL)

# text = "Good night "
# encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='tf')
# output = model(encoded_input)
# scores = output[0][0].numpy()
# scores = softmax(scores)
```

It shows sentiments of all three labels, positive, neutral and negative.

However, I'm now trying to use Finbert from ProsusAI to do sentiment analysis https://huggingface.co/ProsusAI/finbert. It doesn't give me its usage on its page. So I'm following this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/effortless-nlp-using-pre-trained-hugging-face-pipelines-with-just-3-lines-of-code-a4788d95754f.

My code is

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline('sentiment-analysis', model='ProsusAI/finbert')
classifier('Stocks rallied and the British pound gained.')
```

However, the result is `[{'label': 'positive', 'score': 0.8983612656593323}]`. It only shows the sentiment of the most likely label's (positive). But I need all three labels' sentiment (positive, neutral and negative). How should I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the scores for all labels as follows:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
import torch
import scipy

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("ProsusAI/finbert")

inputs = tokenizer("Stocks rallied and the British pound gained.", return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model(**inputs).logits
scores = {k: v for k, v in zip(model.config.id2label.values(), scipy.special.softmax(logits.numpy().squeeze()))}
scores
# {'negative': 0.034473564, 'neutral': 0.067165166, 'positive': 0.8983614}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I ran your code but got ```OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'ProsusAI/finbert'. Make sure that:

- 'ProsusAI/finbert' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
  (make sure 'ProsusAI/finbert' is not a path to a local directory with something else, in that case)

- or 'ProsusAI/finbert' is the correct path to a directory containing relevant tokenizer files```. I looked into this post https://github.com/ProsusAI/finBERT/issues/42, but I didn't use a proxy and have enough disk space. Is it my own problem here?

Comment: I don't get that issue when running the code on google colab, I'm using version 4.20.1 of the transformers library. You might try changing the cache directory in the `from_pretrained` method [using the `cache_dir` argument](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.20.1/en/model_doc/auto#transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained).

Comment: Thank you very much, problem solved on colab. I don't quite understand ```model(**inputs).logits``` now, might need to spend some time to study transformer codes.

Comment: It's simply taken the tokenized input and passing it through the model, and then your taking the logits from the model's output.